# Enum class to constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how to pass *enum* variables to *contructor* in Java, here is my code. I am totally new in programming. Thank u for all help

```
public class PieceOfJewellery extends Valuable {
    private int amountOfGemstones;
    private enum Material {gold, silver};
    private Material material1 = Material.silver;
    private Material material2 = Material.gold; 

    public PieceOfJewellery(String name, int amountOfGemstones) {
        super(name);
        this.amountOfGemstones = amountOfGemstones;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with ` public PieceOfJewellery(String name, int amountOfGemstones, Material mat) {`?

Comment: You do it exactly the same way that you passed your String or int value to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public PieceOfJewlery(String name, int amountOfGemstones, Material material) {
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
public PieceOfJewellery(String name, int amountOfGemstones, Material mat) {
    super(name);
    this.amountOfGemstones = amountOfGemstones;
    this.material1 = mat;
}
```

You can use enums like any other type when you just want to pass them around.

Answer (score 0):

As you write in your question, Enum is a class, so pass it as you would pass any other type defined by a class.